# Opposite of Hmisc::escapeRegex

Tags: r, regex, escaping, gsub

The function `Hmisc::escapeRegex` escapes any special characters in a string.

```
library(Hmisc)
string <- "this\\(system) {is} [full]."
escapeRegex(string)
```

It is based on the `gsub` and `regexp`.

```
escapestring <- gsub("([.|()\\^{}+$*?]|\\[|\\])", "\\\\\\1", string)
escapestring 
[1] "this\\\\\\(system\\) \\{is\\} \\[full\\]\\."
```

How to remove the backslashes from `escapestring` so that the original `string` is retrieved?

Comment: Something like `gsub("\\", "", x)` but this will also remove any `\\` in your original string.

Comment: The most difficult part of this task will be to recognize that the `"\\("` was in the original, since `"("` is a regex meta character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually only need to keep the character after each `\` to un-escape.

```
string <- "this\\(system) {is} [full]."
library(Hmisc)
gsub("\\\\(.)", "\\1", escapeRegex(string))

#> [1] "this\\(system) {is} [full]."
```

Alternatively [rex](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rex/index.html) may make both escaping and un-escaping a little simpler.

```
library(rex)
re_substitutes(escape(string), rex("\\", capture(any)), "\\1", global = TRUE)

#> [1] "this\\(system) {is} [full]."
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the regex

```
\\\\([.|()\\^{}+$*?]|\\[|\\])
```

replacing with capture group `\1`

**Example usage**

```
escapestring <- "this\\\\\\(system\\) \\{is\\} \\[full\\]\\."
string <- gsub("\\\\([.|()\\^{}+$*?]|\\[|\\])", "\\1", escapestring)
string
[1] "this\\(system) {is} [full]."
```

Comment: (Not downvoter). You should update your regex above with what you actually use, and `]` and `[` can be placed inside the character class.

Comment: @nhahtdh Thank you. I have updated my regex. I havn't included `[` `]` in the character class because i just copied the version op was using

Answer (score 1):

May be this also helps

```
gsub("\\\\[(](*SKIP)(*F)|\\\\", '', escapestring, perl=TRUE)
#[1] "this\\(system) {is} [full]."
```